# My footer is not responsive - how to make it responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a two column footer that doesn't resize when I make my browser smaller (columns just stack on to of each other) and hit the 3rd breakpoint in media queries. Any idea what should I change? Complete fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/Cilvako/9wkquboa/

```
<footer>

  <div class="small_left">
    <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet shoulder spare ribs venison cow salami, turducken ham hock tail bacon tri-tip. Ground round jowl filet mignon cupim. Drumstick ribeye porchetta cow andouille. Jerky sirloin kevin ribeye salami doner ground round. Beef ribs pork
      porchetta meatloaf doner swine jowl tail kielbasa tenderloin frankfurter rump meatball. Beef meatball jerky andouille, corned beef doner chicken tri-tip pastrami porchetta spare ribs ham meatloaf. Bresaola capicola frankfurter filet mignon turducken</p>
  </div>
  <div class="small_right">
```

Turducken cow tenderloin, landjaeger fatback beef pork doner brisket boudin leberkas salami tongue. Pork belly biltong tongue alcatra turducken rump doner venison ham hock pig leberkas landjaeger sirloin kielbasa. Cow bacon t-bone ball tip kielbasa.

© Silvia Bogdan, 2015

```
footer {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: BrandonGrotesque-Regular, "futura-pt-1", "futura-pt-2", Verdana, serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  clear: both;
}
/*left div footer*/

.small_left {
  border: 1px solid black;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 13px;
}
/*right div footer*/

.small_right {
  border: 1px solid black;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  height: 175px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

and the Media Query where I get in trouble:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  footer {
    width: 100%;
    font-family: BrandonGrotesque-Regular, "futura-pt-1", "futura-pt-2", Verdana, serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    clear: both;
    /*border: 1px blue solid;*/
  }
  /*left div footer*/
  .small_left {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 44%;
    height: 252px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 12px;
    float: left;
  }
  /*right div footer*/
  .small_right {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 44%;
    height: 252px;
    height: 175px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: justify;
    float: right;
  }
}
```

Comment: You have heaps of invalid HTML. eg.  `<div class="small_right"`, `<p id="footer_copyright">&copy; Silvia Bogdan, 2015</div>`. You should indent your code correctly so you don't miss things like that.

Comment: try *tickling* it  (Thank you, thank you... here all week, try the veal!) ;)

Comment: Yes, true, I think I've deleted them while changing things over and over again. I corrected them but this didn't affect the result though, the divs are still stacking weird when re-sizing the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't specifying any CSS for smaller screens.  So it will go back to your default CSS rules.  Your default rules have no width specified for these divs so it uses the default of 100%.

If you want this to change you need to add another media section for small screens.

```
@media screen and (max-width : 768px) {
   // put your rules here
}
```

Comment: I am a bit confused, I didn't do this in this media query: @media screen and (min-width : 481px) and (max-width :  768px) ?

Comment: If you have something with those rules, they are not in your question.  But even so, if you have a min-width anything smaller will still use the default rules.  Leave the min-width off completely when specifying for the smallest screen.

Comment: Oh, I see you have that in your fiddle.  But there are no rules related to the footer within that media query.

Comment: I couldn't post the whole code here so I put a link to the fiddle with the whole code, sorry about that. So I guess after all the problem is in the breakpoints.

Comment: Ok, my bad now I understand, I didn't asked the question correct. I have no rules for that width because I want the default rules to apply so I want the two columns of the footer to take 100% of the width. My problem is when I hit 769px and I want my columns to appear one next to another (each taking 50% of the width) but they appear one on top of eachother, like in a chess pattern. Does it make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your code over before asking a question.

You haven't ended a starting tag

```
<div class="small_right">
```

Comment: Yup, so I did, I missed them.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed there are some unclosed HTML tags so
correct all markup issues before modifying your CSS.

I suggest you to use **box-sizing: border-box** in order avoid trivial calculation of the width.

Add this on top of your CSS file

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

I saw in your code: `width:47%;`

If you use box sizing border-box then all padding and borders will be set as part of the actual width of your div, defined in your CSS. So your footer would not break after setting the width as 50% and float left, float right to your two footer containers.

Simply correct your media query for mobile, and add to each footer divs:

```
// Add your ideal mobile breakpoint

@media screen and (max-width : 640px) {  

        .small_left {
            width:50%;     
            float:left;
        }
        .small_right {
            width:50%;     
            float:right;
        }     

}
```